# What does msg mean in Mirth?

Tags: mirth

I'm trying to learn my way around some Mirth code. I keep seeing things like this in the transformer for different channels:

```
msg['PRB']['PRB.4']['PRB.4.2'].toString()
```

I understand that this is parsing a HL7 message and I understand that msg probably means message. But is `MSG` a system-wide variable? Does every channel have a `msg` variable? What is the scope of `msg`? I also keep seeing things like `${message.encodedData}` in the Templates. Do certain connector types automatically send the contents of `msg`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The msg variable is the current instance of the **inbound message** that you will use for routing or mapping. It only exists in the context of the mapping/transformation that you are applying and is not system-wide. The message that will be transmitted is referred to as **tmp**. So, when you are mapping, you will be going from msg -> tmp.

Comment: hi, where can we find some documentation on msg functions