# How to loop over all the headers in hl7 message in mirth?

Tags: javascript, hl7, mirth, mirth-connect

I'm new to mirth and trying to loop over all the hl7 message headers in mirth,
I know that I can loop over one header like this:

```
for each(var OBX in msg['OBX']) {
    logger.info('message OBX obj: ' + OBX['OBX.3']['OBX.3.2'].toString());
}
```

but what I need is to loop over all the headers not one so I'm trying to do something like this:

```
for each(var header in msg) {
        logger.info('message header: ' + header.toString());
}

for each(var header in msg['HL7Message']) {
    logger.info('message header: ' + header.toString());
}
```

but this is not working and also I can't convert the hl7 to json please help and many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found a way to loop over, the msg variable is the current instance of the inbound message

```
for each (seg in msg.elements()) {
 logger.info('message elements: ' + JSON.stringify(seg.name().toString()));
}
```

some useful links:

```
https://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?t=6902&page=2
http://www.mirthproject.org/community/forums/showthread.php?t=12334
https://wso2.com/project/mashup/0.2/docs/e4xquickstart.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601712/what-does-msg-mean-in-mirth
```

Comment: @Shamil first thank you for your great comment, and second can you post the link for  the two code snippets.

Comment: @Fadi: How do you like me to post the link? Link to where? Open any channel, open filter or transformer editor, select "Reference" tab and look for "iterate ..." functions in the list. Drag and drop those to your JS step.